# Can I change the App Service Plan/App Service to use the App Services Environment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, ase

I first created the App Service Plan and App service and later created the App Services Environment. Now I want to change the App Service Plan to use the newly configured ASE, but not able to change it. I created another App Service Plan to use the ASE, but then it was not visible under the Change App Service Plean within App Services.

I created another App Service Plan to use the ASE, but then it was not visible under the Change App Service Plean within App Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If apps have already been deployed into existing App Service Plan. Unfortunately there is no straight way option to move to an ASE.

All you can do is to **[clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#cloning-an-existing-app-to-an-app-service-environment)** it into a new ASP which has been deployed into your ASE or redeploy the app in ASE.

Follow this for more information : **[Cloning an existing App to an App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#cloning-an-existing-app-to-an-app-service-environment)**